# Alphabet implementation by Factory Method

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

Does it goo idea to implement alphabet by factory method?

Example:

```
public class Alphabet
{
    public Alphabet(image picture, string name)
    {
       _picture = picture;
       _name = name;
    }

    public void Show()
    {
       _picture.Show();
    }
}

public LetterA: Alphabet
{
    public LetterA() : Alphabet("lttrA.png", "Letter A"){}
}

....


public LetterZ: Alphabet
{
    public LetterZ() : Alphabet("lttrZ.png", "Letter Z"){}
}
```

using:

```
Alphabet ltr1 = new LetterA();
```

Requirements: pictures will be never change, no adding methods in future

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factory method provides a new instance of a class on each invocation. In your case, there's no need to create multiple instances, you can create an enum for the alphabets.

```
public enum Alphabet
{
    A(/*some image*/, "A"),
    B(/*some image*/, "B"),
    C(/*some image*/, "C"),
    D(/*some image*/, "D");
    // ... and so on till Z

    private final String name;
    private final Image picture;

    private Alphabet(Image picture, String name)
    {
       this.picture = picture;
       this.name = name;
    }

    public void Show()
    {
       picture.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, i need 26 classes and in additional method Instance (because of singleton).
But, 26 classes remains 26 classes? I mean, there can be other way to implement alphabet, without sub-classes explosion? Thanks.

Comment: My point was that factory method is not relevant in this case. I've modified my earlier code to use enum instead of multiple singletons. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want 26 subclasses? If I understand you want to map from a string letter to an image file. A simple map would be absolutely sufficient. And maybe a method to handle access to that map, to check that only letters are passed, normalizes them (to-uppercase), ...